# Adding a text field with click of a button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below I have the javascript and html which I currently have in my project. I want a text input field which looks identical to the first one in the html code to appear right beneath it after the 'ADD' button is clicked.

At the moment the added text fields do appear, but they appear under the 'Add' button and they appear next to each other not under each other.

```
<script>    
    function add_field() 
    {
        var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0],
        input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input.setAttribute('name', 'item');
        form.appendChild(input);
    };
</script>
<form name="input" method="get">
    <div class="ui-input-text">
        <input type="text" name="item"><br>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <button type="button" onclick="add_field()">ADD</button><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple demonstration that achieves what you're looking for:

```
<form name="input" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="item">
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="add_field()">ADD</button>
```

css:

```
input {
  display: block;
}
```

**Some helpful notes:**

Don't use `<br>` for spacing elements. Instead, use css styles like `display: block` and `margin`.

Inline js (like onlick in your html) can have some nasty side effects and is not a good practice for a lot of reasons, read some of these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

Instead of inline js, you could do this:

```
//get button reference
var myBtn = document.getElementById('myBtn');

//add click function
myBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  addField();
});
```

You have some `div` tags in your form that close outside of the form. If an element begins inside of another element, be sure to close it before closing the parent element.

**Here's a demo of all of this: http://jsbin.com/igoVoTEr/1/edit**

If you need the button to be inside of the form, you could insert the inputs before it, like this:

```
function addField() {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  //insert before the button
  form.insertBefore(input, myBtn);
}
```

**Live demo here: http://jsbin.com/igoVoTEr/2/edit**